# Populate dropdown with values dynamically from data set

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a dropdown that I am trying to populate dynamically using the following data set

```
this.additionalPercentages = this.offer.offerData.wellbeing.retirementPackages[0].additionalVoluntaryContributionPercentages;
```

`this.additionalPercentages` is consoled and looking like this: `[5, 6]`

```
<p-dropdown
      (onChange) = "getAdditionalPercentage($event)"
      class="fund-dropdown"
      [options]="additionalPercentages"
      [showClear]="false"
></p-dropdown>
```

After doing this, I see that the dropdown is blank with no errors in the console either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`options` takes

> An array of objects to display as the available options.

So you need to change your `additionalPercentages` into array of objects i.e.

```
[
  {label: 5, value: 5},
  {label: 6, value: 6}
]
```

**Code:**

```
this.additionalPercentages=this.additionalPercentages.map(
      (item)=>({label:item,value:item}));
```